# Enable tabbing through links, on page containing input elements

Tags: html, cross-browser, accessibility, tabindex, keyboard-navigation

I want to enable the user to tab through the links of a page.

This is the default behavior in most browsers, but as soon as the page contains an `input` element, it becomes (depending on the browser) the only tabbable element on the page, making e.g. `a` elements inaccessible by keyboard. This doesn't change if `tabindex` is set or not.

See the following example. Focus the input element and press `tab` a few times; While Chrome will focus the links, Firefox and Safari will skip those elements.

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" tabindex="0">
     <button tabindex="0">send</button>
  </form>
</div>
<a href="#" tabindex="0">Link</a>
<a href="#" tabindex="0">Link</a>
```

How can I achieve a cross-browser keyboard navigation without JavaScript and circumvent this problem?

Comment: Are the problems you're describing all occuring on a Mac?

Comment: @Josh Yes, I haven't checked the behavior on different OS's.

Comment: As Josh says below, it's a known behavior of Safari.  Not sure why Apple chose to do that.  You just have to change the setting in Safari and the Keyboard settings.  It's the first thing I do when I get a new Mac.  Frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there is problem that you need to fix here.

Apple handles accessibility a little differently, and there are user preferences that must be enabled to allow for tabbing between links. This behavior is well known in the accessibility community, and I would not recommend implementing any custom solutions to modify this behavior, as it will likely only create other problems.

This article explains in more detail:
http://www.weba11y.com/blog/2014/07/07/keyboard-navigation-in-mac-browsers/